# I'm getting IntegrityError at /cart/ in Django ecommerce Duplicate entry

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to build an e-commerce website and when I try to add a customer to the cart through Mixin I get this error.

This is my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
mobile = PhoneField(unique=True)
registered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    full_name = self.first_name + ' ' + self.middle_name + ' ' + self.last_name
    return full_name

class Meta:
    ordering = ['first_name']


class Cart(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return 'Cart:' + str(self.id)


class CartProduct(models.Model):
cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
size = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
subtotal = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return 'Cart:' + str(self.cart.id) + 'CartProduct:' + str(self.id)
```

this is my views.py

```
class CustomerToCartMixin(object):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cart_id = request.session.get('cart_id')
    if cart_id:
        cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.customer:
            cart_obj.customer = request.user.customer
            cart_obj.save()
        else:
            pass
    return super(CustomerToCartMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
class CartView(CustomerToCartMixin, generic.TemplateView):
template_name = 'accounts/cart.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CartView, self).get_context_data()
    cart_id = self.request.session.get('cart_id', None)
    if cart_id:
        cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
    else:
        cart_obj = None
    context['cart'] = cart_obj
    return context
```

The error I'm getting please help me it also shows the error is in the cart_obj.save() in views.py CustomerToCartMixin.

```
IntegrityError at /cart/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '8' for key 'accounts_cart.Accounts_cart_customer_id_7871070b_uniq'")
Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/

Django Version: 3.1.4

Exception Type: IntegrityError

Exception Value:    
(1062, "Duplicate entry '8' for key 'accounts_cart.Accounts_cart_customer_id_7871070b_uniq'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer, but I think you are missing a:

```
cart_obj = form.save(commit=False)
```

right before you define cart_obj.

That would prevent the object from saving on submit, before defining all the values you want to set, otherwise it will try to save it as a duplicate (with same id, thats why its giving you a "Duplicate entry '8', with 8 being the id value) with the different values you set.